# XPath for text following other text?

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath

I am a beginner in python.  Sorry for this easy question, but I just cannot get the value.  How can I get the number "10655140"?

```
<HEAD>
<BASE target="_top">
<TITLE>United States Patent: 10655140</TITLE></HEAD>
```

My code is below which doesn't work.

```
html.xpath('//HEAD[contains(text(),"United States Patent")]//TITLE/text()')
```

Answer (score 0):

This XPath,

```
substring-after(/HEAD/TITLE, "United States Patent: ")
```

will select the substring *after* "United States Patent: " in the string value of the `TITLE` child of the `HEAD` root element, as requested:

```
10655140
```

Note that the `BASE` open tag is not closed in your markup.